# Save and compare time in integer

Tags: java, date, time, calendar, integer

In my app I have to compare two time values which are stored in an integer variable. All values here are in the 24h format. I use this code the generate the values:

```
Calendar c    = Calendar.getInstance();

int startTime = startHour * 60 + startMin;
int endTime   = endHour * 60 + endMin;
int now       = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 60 + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Now I have to check if the `currentTime` is between the `startTime` and the `endTime`. Of course I can check this with this condition:

```
if(startTime <= now && endTime >= now) 
// between...
```

That works great in most cases but if the `startTime` is bigger than the `endTime` of cause it does not work. Let's take this example: It is now 02:00 o'clock

```
int startTime = 1395; // 23:15
int endTime   = 270;  // 04:30
int now       = 120;  // 02:00
```

Now the if condition does not work. Any ideas how I can solve this? I have to save the values in integer variables not Calendar or Date Objects or something else.

By the way I think the idea (not my own) to store the time in this way only with integer is great. It uses so less memory and with the `modulo` and `divider` operator it is so easy to get the real hour and minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just edit your if statement to check if the startTime was on a different day (startTime > endTime). If so, 'now' is in between those if it's either >= startTime or <= endTime:

```
if(startTime <= now && endTime >= now || (startTime > endTime && (now <= endTime || now >= startTime)))
```

Comment: You are right thank you! I spend so much time on this problem that I forget to check if the `startTime > endTime`. That's of of course important. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, it was a nice thing to solve, and I agree that this is a cool way of dealing with time!

Answer (score 0):

You might normalize the variables early, so that the later code is simpler and easier to read:

```
public void doSomething(int st, int et) {
   int startTime = Math.min(st, et);
   int endTime = Math.max(st, et);
   ...
```

Both Calendar and Date are fairly non-intuitive to work with;  if you will be doing a lot of time manipulation, [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is probably a better choice, with classes for things like time periods and durations and comparing them.